# Problems when building the back using ORM Prisma

Tags: node.js, express, prisma

node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/library.d.ts:1161:35 - error TS1005: '?' expected.

1161     select: infer S extends object;
~

node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/library.d.ts:1163:36 - error TS1005: '?' expected.

1163     include: infer I extends object;
~

Found 2 errors. Alguém ja passou por isso?

Comment: Hi, please note, this is an english-only site. anyway. Anyway, take a look at [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Thank you